# Create a mail with a link to a GDrive Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

in a Google Apps script, I want to send a mail, with an attachment to a DriveApp.Folder object.

I can achieve this getting the folder url, and inserting it in the mail message body, but is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Massimo

Comment: what exactly do you have in mind when you say "with an attachment to a DriveApp.Folder object" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other productized way to achieve this. You could insert some more complex HTML to style the link, etc, if you want it to look more polished.